# How to check async method throws with FsCheck?

Tags: c#, f#, fscheck, property-based-testing

I want to define async property which is about throwing an exception asynchronously. 
However, I could find only `Prop.throws` which accepts `lazy`, but not `Asyn`, `Task` or `ValueTask`.

Isn't async supported?

Comment: AFAIK, the release versions of FsCheck don't support async, while the prerelease versions do. This has been the status quo for quite a few years now. I'm not sure this issue is the most recent word on this topic, but it was what I could dig up on short notice: https://github.com/fscheck/FsCheck/issues/167

Comment: @MarkSeemann Yes, I saw this issue, but it was closed in 2017 =) My expectation was that since then the support was added.

Comment: I don't think it is. IIRC, the `async` support is only in the version 3 branch, and version 3 is still only available as prerelease.

Comment: https://github.com/fscheck/FsCheck/issues/579